# What are distances, metrics, or divergences to determine if one sample comes from components of a distribution

Tags: distributions, distance, divergence

I have a distribution that, wlog, can be defined as a mixture of component distributions $\mathscr{D} = \alpha_{1}\mathscr{D}_{1} + \alpha_{2}\mathscr{D}_{2} + \dots$.  Is there a metric, distance, or divergance that can tell if a sample was drawn from a *subset* of those component distributions?

Comment: If "a sample" means "one sample" this sounds impossible. Can you give more details on what kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: By sample, I mean “a set of $N \geq 1$ realizations”. I intended it to have the same meaning as a sample in a “two-sample” test.

I think for the case of $N=1$ (what I believe you mean by “one sample”), the probability density function of the mixture is a measure that would do this. I’m wondering if there’s a way to do it with $N\geq 1$.